# How to send a string to an express server with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am new to web development so any help is much appreciated.

I need to send a plain text to the server so I can apply MathJax to it.

```
sendForTeX (text) {
  console.log('Sending ' + text + ' to be converted to LaTeX...')
  axios.post('/tolatex', text)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

On the server side, first I use, `body-parser`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Then, I define a middleware to typeset the text.

```
function toLatex (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  MathJax.typeset({
    math: req.body,
    format: 'TeX',
    svg: true,
    mml:false,
  }, function (data) {
    if (!data.errors) {
      req.LaTeX = data
      return next()
    } else {
      console.log('BRRRRUUU')
    }
  })
}
```

Finally, I handle the post request by sending back the new data

```
app.post('/tolatex', toLatex, function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.LaTeX)
})
```

Having read some literature, my understanding is that the text that I send from the client will be in `req.body`, but the output of `console.log(req.body)` is an object of the form `text: ''` where `text`is the text I sent from the client. Then, node immediately crashes with the message `TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value`

I would really appreciate some guidance here.

**UPDATE:** Some poking around leads me to believe that

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

should be replaced by

```
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
app.use(jsonParser)
```

and the plain text should be wrapped in an object `e.g. {plaintext: text}`. This seems to work fine. Would I be correct in concluding that we can't POST a simple string?

Comment: can you show what `req.body` contains ?

Comment: I think this `math: req.body,` should be `math: req.body.text`

Comment: @SagarJajoriya yup, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type of your text variable? It should be object with field text, then you can extract it with req.body.text..

According to your update, I think that you should always send to server an object with keys and values, then in server side you can extract concrete data from your request body with the necessary keys.

Comment: Thanks! Yea...I was sending plain old text.